# THREE.js Orbital controls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've started looking at THREE.js and have built a basic rotating globe based on some examples out there. I'm trying to add orbital controls but not having any luck. I keep getting the following error in the console log

Uncaught TypeError: _threeJs2.default.OrbitControls is not a function

```
the code is below
var posX = 200;
var posY = 400;
var posZ = 1800;
var width = document.getElementById('main').getBoundingClientRect().width;
var height = 600;

var FOV = 45;
var NEAR = 2;
var FAR = 4000;

var clock=new THREE.Clock();
var rotationSpeed = 0.02;
var controls;

// some global variables and initialization code
// simple basic renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width,height);
renderer.setClearColor( 0xfff1e0, 1);

// add it to the target element
var globeDiv = document.getElementById("globeDiv");
globeDiv.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// setup a camera that points to the center
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV,width/height,NEAR,FAR);
camera.position.set(posX,posY, posZ);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

// create a basic scene and add the camera
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(camera);

//spotlight set up in the same location as the camera
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0, 200 );
light.position.set(posX,posY,posZ);
scene.add(light);

//Add Earth
var earthGeo=new THREE.SphereGeometry(650,60,60);
var earthMat=new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
earthMat.map=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/world.jpg");
earthMat.bumpMap=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/bumpmap.jpg");
earthMat.bumpScale=12;
earthMat.shininess=4
var earthObject = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeo,earthMat);
scene.add(earthObject);

//Add clouds
var cloudGeo=new THREE.SphereGeometry(650,60,60);
    var cloudsMat=new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        opacity: 0.17,
        transparent: true,
        color: 0xffffff
    });
    cloudsMat.map=THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/clouds.png");
     var meshClouds = new THREE.Mesh( cloudGeo, cloudsMat );
    meshClouds.scale.set(1.015, 1.015, 1.015 );
    scene.add( meshClouds );

render();

function render() {
    var timer = Date.now() * 0.0001;
    camera.position.x=(Math.cos(timer)*1800);
    camera.position.z=(Math.sin(timer)*1800);
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    light.position.x = (Math.cos(timer)*1800);
    light.position.z = (Math.sin(timer)*1800) ;
    light.lookAt(scene.position);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render );
}


  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

Any help appreciated. I'd also welcome any suggestions on good books or tutorial on this. I'd be interested in knowing how well it integrates with d3 if anyone has experience.
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the OrbitControls script before you can use it:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>`

Also, you dont need the EventListener when you are continuosly rendering the scene anyways.

Comment: @Bob Haslett if that solved your question, please mark it as answered.